# CNNにおけるループ処理の実装

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, keras

## 質問

以下のような動作をするCNNをKerasまたはTensorFlowで実装したいです. 
ループ部分と多数決部分の実装法を教えていただきたいです．(CNN部分は大丈夫です)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 条件

- 学習するCNNは単一のものを2*2のブロックに適用したいです
- ブロックの分割は格子状に行います
- 多数決はCNNで導出した確率を元に行いたいです

## 発生している問題

実装の際に，途中のループ処理の部分の文法がわからず困っています．
通常の機械学習では画像一枚へCNNを一回適用して判定結果を出すのに対して
このモデルではCNNを2*2回適用して，集計結果を最終的な判断としているためループが必要となってしまいます．

## ソースコード

```
def set_vgg_model():
    inputs = Input(shape=(2174, 2174, 3)) #入力画像
    x = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize_images(image, (224*2, 224*2)))(inputs)　#画像のリサイズでCNNの入力層に合わせる
    x = Lambda(lambda image: block_transform(image, mode="channel"))(x) #ブロックに分割

    #モデル作成でここからをループ処理にしたい

    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv1')(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block1_pool')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block2_pool')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block3_pool')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block4_pool')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv2')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='block5_conv3')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='block5_pool')(x)
    flattened = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(flattened)
    x = Dropout(0.5, name='dropout1')(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5, name='dropout2')(x)
    predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

    #ループ処理はここまで

    fin_pred = Lambda(lambda p: voting(p))(predictions) #多数決処理
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
    return model 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    # モデル作成
    input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
    model = set_vgg_model()

    # モデルをプロットする。
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', 
               show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    #sys.exit()

    # 多クラス分類を指定
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9),#Adam(lr=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False), 
              metrics=['accuracy'])


    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = set_tensor()

    # Fine-tuning
    history = model.fit(x_train, 
                            y_train, 
                            batch_size=batch_size, 
                            epochs=nb_epoch,
                            validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
                            verbose=1, 
                            shuffle=True)
```

## 実装上の疑問

- ループ処理はモデル定義内で実装することは可能なのか．(main内で実装することになるのか，またはそもそもKerasでは不可能なのか)

Comment: この内容だけだと「代わりにコードを書いて下さい」という依頼にも受け取れてしまうので、できれば作りかけでも構わないのでコードを載せて貰った方がピンポイントでアドバイスが付けやすいかなと思います ("Pythonでループ処理を記述するための文法が分からない"ということでしょうか)。

Comment: 細かな指摘になりますが、フローチャート図で「ループの終わり (下側)」は上下が逆向きかなと。

Comment: 失礼しました．ソースコードを添付しました．フローチャートの指摘もありがとうございます．

Comment: teratailの質問が削除されてしまって、向こうについていたコメントへの返信が消えてしまいましたね。